# How to add new language pack in Venia PWA?

Tags: pwa-studio, venia

I am using Venia theme in frontend and frontend is seprate from magento setup. I am trying to add new language package for frontend, I tried to google but very less information is available.
Eg. https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/guides/general-concepts/internationalization/

Any link or document will be helpful.